# Visualization of double induction.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, intuition, visualization

I have just learnt double induction and I want to make sure that my interpretation is correct.

**Theorem**

Let, $P(m,n)$ be a statement for $m,n\in \mathbb N$.Suppose,

$(1)$ $P(1,n)$ is true for all $n\in \mathbb N$ and $P(m,1)$ is true for all $m\in \mathbb N$.

$(2)$ For $m_0,n_0>1$, $P(m_0-1,n_0)$ and $P(m_0,n_0-1)$ are true $\implies$ $P(m_0,n_0)$ is true.

Then $P(m,n)$ is true for all $m,n\in \mathbb N$.

I want to give a visual interpretation of why this should be true.Consider the following diagram:

[image]

I want to conclude that for any $m_0,n_0\in \mathbb N$ the statement $P(m_0,n_0)$ is true.So,let us take an example when $(m_0,n_0)=(3,4)$,we claim that $P(3,4)$ is true.$P(3,4)$ is true if its left one and bottom one are true and they are true if their left and bottom ones are true which ultimately boils down to $(3,1),(2,1)$ and $(1,2),(1,3),(1,4)$ being true as the arrows suggest in the diagram.But these are indeed true because $P(m,1)$ and $P(1,n)$ are true for all $m,n\in \mathbb N$.Similarly for any $(m,n)$ in this array,we can reach $(m_0,n_0)$ by checking if the immediate left one and bottom one are true which ultimately lead to $P(1,n)$ and $P(,1)$ being true for all $m,n\in \mathbb N$.Is this explanation correct?

Comment: Yes; basically Induction can be used to compute a specific value going back to the "base". In the double induction case, we have the two bottom lists of values that form the "base" and the computing procedure works backward step by step (one step to the left and one step down) until we reach two values in the bottom lines.